# Python Multi-threading, how to get the class I want

Tags: python, multithreading

I am following a multi-threading tutorial but have trouble understanding it. The tutorial returns `r` as an `int`, but I am looking for `<class 'requests.models.Response'>`. I want to be able to pass this into `pd.read_html` as `r.text` to scrape data. I appreciate any help.

```
url_list = ["https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"+str(STOCK)+"/analysis?p="+str(STOCK)+"","https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/"+str(STOCK)+"/financials/cash-flow"]


    def download_file(url):
        html = requests.get(url, headers = headers, stream=True) #headers = User Agent
        return html.status_code

    processes = []
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        for url in url_list:
            processes.append(executor.submit(download_file, url))

    for task in as_completed(processes):
        r = task.result()
```

Comment: What are you talking about? Which int?

Comment: @pavel I'm guessing the `return html.status_code` returns `int`

Comment: @pavel My apologies, the line ```r = task.result()``` returns an int.

Comment: @biscuit2120: Have the function return `html`, not `html.status_code`?

Comment: You can just change `html.status_code` to simply `html` which will return the Response object.

Comment: I see. Silly mistake on my part. Thanks all.

Comment: "I want to be able to pass this into pd.read_html as r.text to scrape data." Why not just return the text?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, is there a way to do that? I am new to this and trying to learn about it more.

Comment: Okay, so, right now your plan is to create a Response object, and `return` it from somewhere. Then the calling code will examine the `r.text`. My proposal is to do the `r.text` part *before* the `return`. I don't really know how there is anything to explain about it.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel. Yes, I see what you are saying now. That makes more sense. Thank you.